# Ansible: How to iterate over paths in `stat`-provided dictionary?

Tags: python, ansible

I'm trying to use ansible to figure out which of a collection of paths are present and then only act one the ones that exist (it's not just the `copy` as in the example below but also editing further down the line).
Here's what I came up with with - it's the second iteration, I couldn't get anything using `with_item` in the second task to work either.

```
- name: disable plasma - identify files to act on
  stat:
    path: "{{ item }}"
  register:
    plasma_conf
  with_items:
    - "/usr/share/autostart/plasma-desktop.desktop"
    - "/usr/share/autostart/plasma-netbook.desktop"
    - "/etc/xdg/autostart/plasmashell.desktop"

- name: disable plasma - copy config locally
  copy:
    src: "{{ item.item }}"
    dest: "/home/{{ main_user }}/.config/autostart/{{ item.item | basename }}"
  with_dict:
    plasma_conf.results
  when:
    item.stat.exists == true
```

The copy task fails with `fatal: [localhost] => with_dict expects a dict`. How does one make this work based on the `dict` structure provided by `stat`?

Comment: The registered result should be a list of dicts, not a dict, so `with_items` would be correct. What was the issue with `with_items`? In case you haven't done so yet, you could output `plasma_conf` in a debug task to better understand the data structure you're working with: `- debug: var=plasma_conf`

Comment: As @udondan stated - using `- debug: var=plasma_conf` is the best thing you can do to help understand what is required.  So many tasks return lots of disparate information in register variables that the only way to know what's available is to use the debug task to print it out and look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all the comments - `debug` and `with_items` had been used in multiple iterations before, but had failed to produce the output I wanted. I went back, used the tried and true "scrap everything and start from scratch" approach with the following minimalist, self contained example:

```
 ---
 - hosts: 
    localhost
  tasks:
    - name: 
        create testing infrastructure a)
      file:
        path: "/tmp/{{ item }}"
        state: touch
        mode: 744
      with_items:
        - testFileA
        - testFileB
    - name: 
        create testing infrastructure b)
      file:
        path: "/tmp/testDir"
        state: directory
        mode: 744
    - name:
        identify files to act on
      stat:
        path: "{{ item }}"
      register:
        files2move
      with_items:
        - "/tmp/testFileA"
        - "/tmp/testFileB"
        - "/tmp/testFileC"
    - name:
        copy available files
      copy:
        src: "{{ item.item }}"
        dest: "/tmp/testDir/{{ item.item | basename }}"
        mode: 640
      with_items:
        files2move.results
      when:
        item.stat.exists == true
```

I don't really know what's different now, but this works - both in the minimalist version and when ported back into my code ...

Answer (score 0):

`plasma_conf.results` is a list of stat dictionaries.  Replace `with_dict` in your second task with `with_items`.  See http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop, and of course the debug output as suggested by udondan.